# Why can't I see text on the nopad in dark mode?

Tags: lts, bug-reporting, 20.04

[image]
Text from selected line is not visible in dark theme mode.

[image]
However, text is visible in the normal standard-themed mode. I think it's Ubuntu's user interface error.

Comment: I saw this as well in Ubuntu 20.04. I changed to Solarized Dark in Gedit. That fixed it.

Comment: @DKBose However, Ubuntu basically needs to fix the bug. If I post the problem here, will Ubuntu fix the bug?

Comment: So "me too" the bug in the link Kulfy provided.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `highlight line` option in Gedit settings